# Routing latency for normal Signal Gateway in the COM

Tags: autosar

I am trying to understand the routing latency for normal Signal Gateway and the ways in how I can have a different behaviour.

First case:

- I have several Tx I-PDU that I wanted to send. I have configured the send mode to Direct, Tx signal property to triggered, and signal property is immmediate. However, the the Tx I-PDU is sent by the call cycle of Com_MainFunctionTx(). Is there any way to write a signal in a port from a SWC and sent without waiting the call of Com_MainFunctionTx()?

Second case:

- I want to send differents Tx I-PUDs with specific time between them and that time is less than 1ms. For instance:

[image: example_ipdu]

Should I implement a CDD or the COM can have that behaviour?

My question arises because by my understading if I write a signal in a port to be send at the end by CAN the Can_Write() is called in the context of Com_MainFunctionTx(). I do not know if there is something wrong with that.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Not sure, what your question has to do with "signal gateway". There are actually 2 components related to routing: `PduR` for PDU based rounting, `Com` for signal-based routing. In Com, you should actually also call `Com_MainfunctionRouteSignals()`, which does exactly this. But signal based routing is based on the ISignalPdu related triggerrings (PERIODIC, DIRECT, MIXED). To get a 0.12ms stuff, with a 500kB/s HS-CAN, a message takes about 220..260µs on the bus itself, besides, that transmission on CAN is arbitration(prio) based, unless you have TTCAN (not seen at all in 15 years!).

Comment: Thanks for you answer @kasselhaus. The speed is 1MB/s. I'm not sure, if I'm lost, but I think I need to implement a CDD, don't you?. If we forget about 0.12ms and we think about 0.5ms between messages. How could I do that?. I mean imagine that I need to send a group of 10msg each 10ms (the msg group), but between each msg I must meet 0.5ms betwen them.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: a) So, for 1MB/s bittime is 1µs, a Std CAN message with DLC=8 takes 111..131µs on the bus. b) You could also use [AUTOSAR LdCom](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_LargeDataCOM.pdf), see ch. 1 and 4.1, the transmission is triggered directly out of your SWC. c) You could also try using the TxConfirmation to trigger the transmission of the next PDU eg. TxConfPdu1() { trigger Pdu2 } d) I still wonder, why you really care so much about the time between the CanFrames (lke 0.12ms or 0.5ms). What is the real reason for this? Maybe TxOffsets could help?